# Configure app yaml to serve JSON files out of static directories

Tags: json, file, google-app-engine, yaml

I configured my app.yaml like this:

```
- url: /data
  static_dir: templates/data
  http_headers:
    Content-Type: application/json
```

As seen here at [GAE config yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig)

I do an AJAX request to get the JSON;
I have a 1KB "sic.json" there, properly formed (I checked...)

When I run [dev_appserver](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver), 
Using Chrome developer tools, I see the return response as type:

```
Content-Type:application/octet-stream
```

When I retrieve these results in jQuery/Javascript, the string is not recognized as JSON;
if forces me to use JSON.Parse first...

But when I actually deploy, the app yaml configuration seems to work; it serves the static file as JSON so JSON.Parse is unnecessary...

Should I expect this, that dev_appserver doesn't do the same as live deployment as far as serving http_headers for files?

Comment: Sounds like a bug.  You can file a bug report: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?can=2&q=type=Defect&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure `Content-Type` is one the headers meant to be specified within `http_headers`. Assuming you don't have anything else concerning templates/data dir that would imply otherwise  in app.yaml, the following will work as expected:

```
- url: /data
  static_dir: templates/data
  mime_type: application/json
```

Comment: Thanks; there is no other reference to /data or templates/data (but there are references to template/scripts, templates/styles, etc) I tried your suggestion; using mime_type directly. It is behaving the same; still serves **application/octet-stream** (undesirable) when I deploy locally (development), but serves **application/json** when actually deployed to [production](http://slide.nxsxbrl.appspot.com/).... Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: Maybe... I tried it myself before posting the answer (on Mac OS), just to make sure. It worked like a charm. Can you temporary move templates/data into, say, static/data or something and leaving `url: /data` as is. See if that works. It if does, then there's probably something else overrides templates/data settings. Otherwise, could it be that you have another handler mapped to the same /data url?

Comment: Hey @alex, I tried your suggestion, and it worked! So your theory must be correct, maybe something else overrides templates/data settings. Note: I don't know why this isn't true when I deploy to production; do you think it's worth investigating, or do you think it could be a bug?  Also note: I switched back to http-headers: Content-Type:application/json , and that also worked. But the mime_type approach is better. Thanks again!

Comment: Off the top of my head, it might be that some files are being ignored due to app.yaml/skip_files when you deploy to their production servers (or vise versa). OTOH, I don't see how that can impact on mime_type or headers. Another thing: if you're using Jinja2, its default dir for templates is indeed "templates", so that could another reason. But again, I don't see how or why it should be different on dev vs production...